# How to upload JSON Post to a server from a WebClient in C#?

Tags: c#, json, http, post, webclient

I have this API url: `https://faucetbox.com/api/v1/send`

With this API data: `amount=1&to=xxx&api_key=yyy`

And I got this C# code:

```
string JSON_WRITER(string url,string JSON)
{
string result="";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", JSON);
}
return result;
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
JSON_WRITER("https://faucetbox.com/api/v1/send", "amount=1&   to=DSfPc8GkRGF3Xrp99gHQFFJ7hcFJCqkwYH&api_key=4VdBEIAQKPpZ4SWOhQLUMn7mMNVql")
```

However it doesn't work, and it gives the following error:

```
{"status":414,"message":"Missing or invalid parameters."}
```

Can somebody correct the syntax error, if there is any, i`m not that experienced with JSON, or please help me resolve the problem, thanks!

(Don't worry about the API key though, it doesn't reveal private information)

Comment: You need to change your API key **RIGHT NOW** since you just leaked it to the public.

Comment: Nope thats a public API key, dont worry, its in a documentation

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Adding JSON serialization for constructing JSON.

```
 public class Data
 {
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Api_Key { get; set; }

    public string To { get; set; }
 }
```

Serialization code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Data { Amount = 1M, Api_Key = "Some key", To = "some destination" });
```

Add a content type header as below.

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
```

JSON Payload:

```
{"amount":1,"to":"DSfPc8GkRGF3Xrp99gHQFFJ7hcFJCqkwYH","api_key":"4VdBEIAQKPpZ4SWOhQLUMn7mMNVql"}
```

JSON Specification can be found below.
http://json.org/

Comment: How to add that JSON Payload, because my JSON variable is a string, i need to change that.

Comment: How are you constructing the string now? Are you planning to replace the string with an object? And for a string with escape sequence, you can use string payload = "{\"amount\":1,\"to\":\"DSfPc8GkRGF3Xrp99gHQFFJ7hcFJCqkwYH\",\"api_key\":\"4VdBEIAQKPpZ4SWOhQLUMn7mMNVql\"}";

Comment: For one it's not working, and its also looks non efficient. I have the Newtonsoft.Json library, isnt there a better way to do it with that?

Comment: Of course you can do it with Newtonsoft JSON library with a concrete CLR type for your data. That would be the best way to go. Since your question was about JSON formatting, I had posted the JSON format for the URL encoded string you had in the question.

Comment: Updated the code with JSON serialization. Hope this helps.

Comment: It should work, however it still doesnt, i still get the error message 414